# Using btc-e in the United States and depositing/withdrawing USD into btc-e?

Tags: litecoin, withdrawal, btce, usa, funds

I am located in the United States, and was wondering about the complications of using btc-e to make trades in the USA, such as the complications in depositing and withdrawing money in the form of USD.

When I try to deposit USD into btc-e, almost all the options there to deposit money are not supported for US residents such as Perfect Money, OKpay, EgoPay. The other options are Interkassa and Payeer but these sites are in Russian and hard to navigate. There is one more option of wire transfer, but this requires a $2000 minimum. Does anyone have any advice in relation to depositing USD?

Even if we get over the hurdle of depositing USD funds by bypassing it and buying a bitcoin from coinbase and transfering it over to btc-e, and then buying other currencies such as ltc and nmc, eventually when I sell these for USD on btc-e, am I going to have trouble taking the USD out of btc-e? I ask this because it was so hard putting USD in, that I am wondering if it is the same way taking it out?

If anyone in the USA has been using btc-e lately, please advise me on the difficulty or liklihood of depositing USD but more importantly withdrawing USD from btc-e, and how? Thank you.

I guess a second question would be if BTC-e is hard to use in the USA, is there any other exchange in the USA for trading alternative currencies such as LTC, NMC, etc...?

Comment: Note, Wire transfers are not available for US Citizens/US Banks right now, "We don't accept international wire transfers from US Citizens or from US Banks
All transfers from US Citizens or US Bank will be refused by bank"

Comment: This question is about deposits, not withdrawals.  Please edit the tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to buy BTC on Coinbase to xfer to BTC-e, when you want to cash out wouldn't you just trade over to BTC on BTC-e to xfer to Coinbase to sell for USD then withdrawal?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble adding funds to btc-e. Best way to do it is using a wiretransfer. They give you the information you need for your bank to send funds to your account on btc-e.

However the way I added funds is this creat an account with www.virwox.com . You can add USD from your credit card onto your account on the website. From then you have to trade in USD for linden dollers. From there you can transfer the linden dollers into bitcoins. Then send the bitcoins to your btc-e account and there you have it! The most complicated way to get funds onto btc-e.

Depending on how long you have been a member on virwox is dependent how much you can transfer from your credit card.

The reason other sites don't allow adding through use of debit or credit cards for cryptocurrency is because they have a non refund system where credit cards and debit cards have a refund system in place directly contradicting the websites terms and agreements.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if banks in the cayman islands would accept btc-e as deposits in us dollars in a savings account you opened in their bank.  If they did, then you could remotely transfer from your account in the caymen islands to your bank account in the US.  You can remotely open an account in the caymen islands without going there.  Its worth a try...I will have to figure out the answer to that same question soon.